# Mobile Navigation Text

Tags: css, mobile, navigation, squarespace

I have attached a screenshot of the issue I am trying to fix. I used some `css` to get my logo to show up in the navigation while viewing in mobile. But now it doesn't look very good because it says **Job Spark** below in text as well.

Can anyone see a way to change the "**Job Spark**" text to "**Menu**".

Also on a side note.... I am getting a bit of white pixels showing up on the very bottom of the navigation and cant see what is causing this.

www.jobspark.ca is my website. Thanks for taking a look.

UPDATE: Trying to change this menu text with javascript. Tried this code out but didn't seem to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">Y.one("#mobile-navigation-title").set("text", "Menu");</script>
```

[image]

Comment: What does the HTML look like for the logo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CSS, just hide `#mobile-navigation-title` and reposition the existing `#mobile-navigation-label` which is hidden behind the logo element.

```
#mobile-navigation-title { display: none !important; }
#mobile-navigation-label { position: static !important; }
```

You can use more specific selectors if you'd rather not use `!important` (fair enough) but for the sake of brevity, there you go.

Scrap all that JavaScript too, it's redundant.

Answer (score 2):

That text isn't displayed at all until the page switches to a mobile format, so all you have to do is change it in the HTML. If you can't find it, the element is around line 167:

```
<nav id="mobile-navigation">
  <span id="mobile-navigation-title">Job Spark</span>
  <span id="mobile-navigation-label"></span>
  ...
```

To change the text with Javascript, try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Y.on("domready", function() {
        Y.one("#mobile-navigation-title").set("text", "Menu");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @davidbrown , I am using a Squarespace template so have very limited access to the sites html. Can this be targeted using CSS?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Not as far as I'm aware, anyway. You could certainly do it with Javascript, though. See my edited answer for an example.

Comment: hmmm i updated my question with the code i tried but didn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">Y.one("#mobile-navigation-title").set("text", "Menu");</script>` should do the trick. Just remove the second opening `<script>` tag from your snippet. You also already have a site.js file, which would be a good place to put that without the HTML tags (if you can edit it).

Comment: Frick sorry dude can you show me what you mean. I will edit my question above to what I have. feel free to edit the code to what your wanting me to do.

Comment: Sorry; my fault. I forgot to delay execution until the DOM had loaded. See my answer for the updated script block.